# Adding a Column to Vaadin Table object after table creation

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm wondering if there's a proper way to add a column to an existing Vaadin Table object.  I'd like my other devs to create tables, pass them into my `CustomTableComponent` and have it automatically add a control column at the end. Here's a brief overview of the situation:

- I am trying to add a column to any table passed into my `CustomTableComponent(Table existingTable)`;
- currently `existingTable.setVisibleItemProperties(col1, col2, etc)` has been called BEFORE this column needs to be added
- I can pass a generic "extra column" id in `setVisibleItemProperties()` but that puts the requirement on the dev to know about it in advance. This however DOES work if I use a columnGenerator with that same id.
- calling `setVisibleItemProperties()` again appears to be frowned upon on various Vaadin forum posts

Has anyone run into this while creating a custom editable table or similar situation?  How did you handle it?  How did you handle the corresponding column width changes if you succeeded?

Comment: Thank you, Hopper, for the cleanup :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about doing it edit style, but I ran at the similar problem when I wanted to use table as an image grid (with lazy load). I resolved that by simply assigning the table new data source, which in turn reflected into the columns.

Comment: If that works out, I'll report back.  Unfortunately I'm trying to make it generic so any data source can be attached and this method will add to it...  Perhaps I can pull the data source, add to it and then reassign it.  Thanks!